# How to make The AppBarToggleButton Label cover the entire area on it?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, controls

[image]

I don't want to display `Icon` on `AppBarToggleButton`. So I deleted the default `Icon="Accept"` from XAML. But the area for the icon is left behind. I want to display the label only and entirely covered on the `AppBarToggleButton`. I couldn't find a property to do so. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom `AppBarToggleButton` Style to suit your needs.

I have copied the default style by right clicking the `AppBarToggleButton` in the designer and choosing **Edit template** and then **Edit a copy**:

```
<Style x:Key="LabelOnlyAppBarToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="AppBarToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="68"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarToggleButton">
                <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="FullSize"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                <Storyboard>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LabelOnRight">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentViewbox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="12,14,0,14"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextAlignment">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Left"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="8,15,12,17"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LabelCollapsed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithMenuIcons">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.MaxWidth" Value="16"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.MaxHeight" Value="16"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Margin" Value="38,0,12,0"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Margin" Value="76,0,12,0"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="AccentOverlayBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundHighLightOverlayPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonOverflowLabelForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="AccentOverlayBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundHighLightOverlayPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonOverflowLabelForegroundPressed}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonOverflowLabelForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrushChecked}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundChecked}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundChecked}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundChecked}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="AccentOverlayBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundHighLightOverlayCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonOverflowLabelForegroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="AccentOverlayBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundHighLightOverlayCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonOverflowLabelForegroundCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonOverflowLabelForegroundCheckedDisabled}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowNormal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowPointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="AccentOverlayBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundHighLightOverlayPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonOverflowLabelForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowPressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="AccentOverlayBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundHighLightOverlayPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonOverflowLabelForegroundPressed}"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowChecked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrushChecked}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundChecked}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundChecked}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundChecked}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowCheckedPointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="AccentOverlayBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundHighLightOverlayCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonOverflowLabelForegroundCheckedPointerOver}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowCheckedPressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBorderBrushCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForegroundCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="AccentOverlayBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundHighLightOverlayCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Fill" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonOverflowLabelForegroundCheckedPressed}"/>
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedHighlightBackground.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Margin" Value="12,12,12,12"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="GameControllerInputMode">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13"/>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowCheckGlyph.Margin" Value="12,12,12,12"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="CheckedHighlightBackground" Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundChecked}" Opacity="0"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="AccentOverlayBackground" Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonBackgroundHighLightOverlay}"/>
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="OverflowCheckGlyph" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{ThemeResource AppBarToggleButtonCheckGlyphForeground}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" Margin="12,6,12,6" Opacity="0" Text="&#xE73E;" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="14"/>
                        <Viewbox x:Name="ContentViewbox" Visibility="Collapsed" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Margin="0,14,0,4">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="12" Margin="2,0,2,6" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="OverflowTextLabel" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="38,0,12,0" Padding="0,5,0,7" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" TextTrimming="Clip" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have made just a few changes. I have changed the `TextLabel` to have `Grid.Row="0"` to be on the first row above the `Content` and then set `Grid.RowSpan="2"` to make it cover the whole container. Next I have searched for `TextLabel` and removed an animation that set its visibility to `Collapsed` for `Compact` `VisualState` `Storyboard`.

Finally I have set `ContentViewbox` `Visibility` to `Collapsed` although this won't have any effect when you don't set any `Icon` or `Content`.

You can use the style like this:

```
<CommandBar>
    <AppBarToggleButton Style="{StaticResource LabelOnlyAppBarToggleButtonStyle}" Label="This is a very long label" />
</CommandBar>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: yeah that worked. Could you point me the VisualStates out, that you've made changes?

Comment: One change was in the `<VisualState x:Name="Compact">` section (removed all content from the `Storyboard`) and then outside of `VisualStates` - `<TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel"` as described in the answer. If that solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved :-) .